# Click to call on each unique number for each post

Tags: tel

I have users posting their own ads on my website, with this they will post a phone number to call them where any visitor can click to call.
At the moment i am using ACF to collect the users phone numbers and I display them on my archive page by a loop template.
Basically each post has a contact number, hence i want to make each of these numbers click to call
I am not dont have a idea on coding all this I have done by using plugins so need some advice how to do this
I used the "tel:" command but then I have to enter each phone number again manually to the box this is not what I want

Please help thanks

Comment: What is your website built in? What code do you use to loop and render the ads? We need a bit more information in order to help you out here.

Comment: Hi @philnash its on wordpress and I am using the loop template in elementor to loop the ads, all the details of the ads are collected with ACF, users can login and post their ads and the phone number is a Text field in ACF so each ad will have a different number. this is my first project and I dont know coding all this i have done by watching youtube tutorials

Comment: Heh, I'm a little out of my depth there too. I don't know what ACF or elementor is either. Can you show, by editing your question, the loop template you are using?